# How to run functional component in useEffect used for updating context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Trying to get the API functional component that updates Context values in `useEffect` to execute within another App functional component (on import) when mounted to allow render when values exist/update.

The API function at `API.js` appears to be working correctly as a stand alone component. The problem (due to lack of understanding) is upon the import to `App.js` where the API function should execute.

API.js

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './contexts/AppContext';

export const API = () => {

  const {updateOrder, updateCustomer} = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const orderDetails = await fetch('url.com/order');
      const customerDetails = await fetch('url.com/customer');
      updateOrder(await orderDetails.json())
      updateCustomer(await customerDetails .json())
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './contexts/AppContext';
import { API } from './components/API';

const App = ({ isLoading }) => {

  const {order, customer} = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    isLoading && <API />

  }, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  if (order && customer) {
    return <SomeComponent/>
  }

}
```

The expected outcome is to be able to use API within the initial mount (as API dependency) and conditionally return/render content in App.

I've tried changing the API component into function and exporting with default, however context is not supported outside of component.

Comment: Context in React allows you to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components through a provider.  It helps you to not have to pass props through multiple levels of your component tree (i.e., prop drilling).  I think you might be looking for a [custom hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) which allows you reuse logic.

Comment: If you check the description above you can tell that the Context is working and the question is not about using the observer pattern. Its applying the principle of having non returnable component as oppose to using class declarations.

Answer (score 2):

A component is a function that renders something in the UI. You `API` component is not really a component - it doesn't have any branch that returns any JSX - although that's not always required.

You should look into building a custom hook instead. Try something like this:

App.js

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./contexts/AppContext";

// Hooks should start with 'use'
export const useAPI = () => {
  const { updateOrder, updateCustomer } = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // Fetching data from both endpoints in parallel
      const res = await Promise.all([fetch("url.com/order"), fetch("url.com/customer")]);

      // Converting both payloads to JSON in parallel
      const data = await Promise.all([res[0].json(), res[1].json()]);

      updateOrder(data[0]);
      updateCustomer(data[1]);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
};

const App = ({ isLoading }) => {
  // Calling the custom hook
  useAPI();

  const { order, customer } = useContext(AppContext);

  if (order && customer) {
    return <SomeComponent />;
  }
};
```

Comment: You should show how to use this hook with op's code because it can't be used in `useEffect`

Comment: Good point; I've updated my answer to show how

Comment: Thats amazing, but can I call the useAPI() within useEffect on App? As I need this dependency to run once upon initial mount of the App